# DataTable Cast Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a question about the cast of an object.
I have a `DataTable dt` that is an Object.
It has data in it like `45.123`
I want to convert it to a `Double` but I am having trouble converting from an Object to a Double hence the Cast errors.

```
double[] M = new Double[11,11];
```

I tried it this way and I got a Cast error:

M[x,1] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[x]["SomeColumn"]);

I also tried:

```
M[x,1] = (double)dt.Rows[x]["SomeColumn"];
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Didn't you get error in `double[] M = new Double[11,11];`??

Comment: Using linq : double[] M = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<double>("SomeColumn")).ToArray();

Comment: A mistype:  double[,] M = new Double[11,11];

Comment: did you tried ..?  `M[x,1] = (double)dt.Rows[x]["SomeColumn"].ToString();`